# I gave my landlord my a N9 form to end a 1 year lease due to allergies and she is refusing to accept it. Is that illegal do I have recourse with LTB?

Tags: breach-of-contract, ontario, breaking-the-lease, mental-health, pets

I have a one year lease, I've only lived in the unit for 2 months. My landlord has lied to me multiple times by making verbal agreements then going back on them. Her lies included other tenants and now me and the other tenants do not get along. She offered an ethernet cable as a work accomodation prior to moving in and after moving in she said it was not included in the lease and tells the rest of the tenants she never promised me that causing problems with me and the other tenants.

On move in day the room was not ready to move in and she said to move in and someone will come after and fix the room, I did not want anyone coming into my room with my items because I've had issues with stalking and harassment (which she's unaware of because who wants the whole world to know about that stuff) and she offered me reduced rent..  after moving in she said how my concern did not constitute for reduced rent.

Recently, She accepted a tenant with a Husky and never asked if anyone has allergies and the person with the dog was in the room beside mine. She said by moving the dog to the basement that will solve the problem. That is not how allergies work and our only common area in the student housing is in the basement. The owner still let's the dog upstairs and the dog goes to both kitchens and everyone plays with the dog and touches everything and recently the dog found a new liking to poo right outside my door (which does not help my allergies) Due to COVID I work from home and I can't work from home because my symptoms are affecting my work I had to temporarily move into my parents house to work. I'm also being monitored by my company because of the ethernet lies my landlord told. I gave my landlord the N9 to end my lease August 31st because I will not be able to study with my allergies and she said I gave her the wrong document, denying my request to terminate. Now she hired a property management company because a family member is ill and said to contact them for any concerns that I have moving forward because we will not be able to contact her.

I contacted them because I had no other choice and they are refusing my termination notice as well saying I'm bound to the lease. They said they will try to remove the dog but based on my experience I do not believe them and I do not want to be forced to live in a unit that uninhabitable for me when school starts. The property management company is now saying that they will keep my last month rent of $550 and ask that I pay them $1100 as a fee to break the lease if I really want to go.

Comment: Note there are two distinct issues in your question: on the one hand the oral promises and reneging on these promises, and on the other hand the dog allergy. In general, don't trust oral promises, try to get everything in writing, and if you can't, having witnesses helps.

Comment: Also, if you're in a meeting with someone who promises something orally: after the meeting, write it down, then send an email to that person that includes the information. This puts the information in writing, and gives that person an opportunity to deny or not deny by responding to the email, and if they don't deny then you have evidence that you can use. You'll find that most people break their oral promises much more easily than promises that have been written down :-)

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to deliver the form: they do not have to accept it. You can deliver it to an office, hand it to the landlord's agent, put it on their desk, mail it or fax it. You will eventually need to involve the [LTB](http://www.sjto.gov.on.ca/ltb/) because you either have to get the landlord to agree, find a replacement tenant, or [appeal to the LTB](https://www.cleo.on.ca/en/publications/moving/legal-ways-move-out-early). If you don't get an assignee and don't get them to agree to let you out of the lease, then you have to appeal to the board. They can let you out of a lease early [for certain reasons](https://www.cleo.on.ca/en/publications/moving/legal-ways-move-out-early#board); they do recommend getting legal aid first.